# Can't get setting Visual Studio 2013 Environment Variables to work

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, environment-variables

I find using the command line to compile my C# sources a lot easier than having to launch resource-intensive VS2013 just to compile one class.

From this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd.aspx) on msdn, all I'm to do is navigate to the right path of my installation in command prompt, to be precise: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools` . Then run the .bat file called `vsvars32.bat`.

Now everything works fine before I close the command prompt window after I run the batch file, I can use the csc compiler now as I don't get the message:

But the minute I close command prompt to launch it again, I'm back at:

`'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I thought it could have something to do with launching command prompt with administrative rights so I did that, launched command prompt as an administrator, ran the batch file again, closed command prompt, relaunched and the dreadful message came back.

I really can't say why this happens as I've checked my Environment Variables in `Computer > Properties > Advanced System Tools` and I have the `VS120COMNTOOLS` variable there.

Comment: `vsvars32.bat` is meant to be called every time when you start a command prompt. If you have multiple versions of visual studio installed, you can choose which version to use, depending on which `vsvars32.bat` you run.

Comment: @Wimmel wow, really, every time? So there's just no way to have it stick?

Comment: there are other command prompts which can simply solve your issue, for example Console2, see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

Comment: Keep the Visual Studio Command Prompt shortcut handy so you can't forget to call vsvars32.bat

Comment: Actually, I use Cmder which emulates the command line excellently, If only I knew a way to have it startup with setting VS's environment variables.

Comment: Just look at the properties of the VSCP shortcut and reproduce that.

Answer (score 2):

In your start menu you can find a "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013"

[image]

By starting that instead of the normal "cmd" it will be configured to use the Visual Studio 2013 command line tools automatically.

All my versions of Visual Studio have always created these, but in case they're missing from your start menu, the shortcut files are stored here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts

[image]

You can pin these to the start menu to make them easy to access if you want to.

The command that underpins the Visual  Studio Command prompt is:

> cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""

Where `/k` starts the command line, then executes the command passed in and then keeps the commandline open.

Comment: That's not commonly available, I don't have it.  The only Search results I get are web pages for programmers that cannot find it either :)  The VS installer always makes the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" available afaik.